# $cu=0\iff u=0\vee c=0$

Tags: vector-spaces

$c$ is a constant in **R** or **C**

$u$ is in a vector space

$cu=\mathbf 0\iff u=\mathbf 0\vee c=0$

First I tried to show the two implications

$cu=\mathbf0\Leftarrow u=\mathbf0\vee c=0$

and

$cu=\mathbf0\Rightarrow u=\mathbf0\vee c=0$

The first one is easy (it is done via two cases, when $c=0$ and when $v=\mathbf0$)

But I don't know how to do the second implication using. I want just a hint.

Comment: Hint: if $cu = 0$ and $c \neq 0$, what happens if you multiply by $c^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If c is non zero then it has an inverse in the field.